# Prefix express.js Routes

Tags: javascript, express

Is there a way to prefix a subset of routes in express.js? I know that you can add a mount point when calling the app.router() but this affects all routes.

I am looking for a way to add */api/v1/* to a bunch of routes instead of applying this to every single route definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[express-namespace](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-namespace) does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution: Check this library, it allows you to softcode your routes and add hierarchies to them. You can add a simple route with no handler that responds to /api/v1 and have all other routes be a child of it.

https://github.com/hrajchert/express-shared-routes