# add prefix for all routes in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am deploying a nodejs project on a server with apache2 reverse proxy.
When i type this in apache:

```
       http://mywebsite/folder1prefix/myroute
```

it redirects me to my node application, but apache use folder1prefix because there are other apps.

The problem is my nodejs use routes like this:

```
       app.all('/myroute', function(req,res) { ... });
```

Is there a way to tell node to ignore folder1prefix prefix. I don t want to do this:

```
       app.all('/folder1prefix/myroute', function(req,res) { ... });
```

Because the folder1prefix purpose is for testing and it can change.

Comment: my wild guess that the question is about express.js and not node.js, correct? If so see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434661/prefix-express-js-routes

Comment: Thanks but i have another problem: I have to add this prefix to each redirection url in my code, and for each link in jade template. Is there a way to hook every url that comes in my app, in order to add this prefix. Thanks